# Implementing Androids Scroll-view with include view in it

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Hi i've used ScrollView before but for some reason it aint working at all right now the greatest problem right now is that the linear_view i've added inside this scrollView aint matching it's parent :| 
[image: ScreenShot]

---

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >





        <include
            android:id="@+id/myPostBox1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            layout="@layout/mycoolpostbox" />

   </LinearLayout> 
 </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**Which part am i doing wrong exactly?Things work just fine if i put the include view inside the linearlayout without the scrollView and the RelativeLayout** 
Here's the code inside the include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_weight="6" >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:background="#848484"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <!-- <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/box1_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> -->

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/postImage1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="6.95" />
            <WebView 
                android:id="@+id/myBody1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
               />
              <!--     <WebView 
                    android:id="@+id/myInfo1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"/> -->

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.05"/>
                <!--   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myInfo2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" /> -->

            </LinearLayout>
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Here's what i want to get in the end :D 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try with the property isFillViewport so the scrollview can stretch

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#isFillViewport()

Comment: hi i used  android:fillViewport="true" and the problem of the LinearView height thing is solved but i cant scroll right now any where else  i might have made a mistake ?

Comment: get rid of the relative layout as a parent put instead a linear vertical layout

Comment: Hi i tired that too..not solving the problem..i had a more basic problem i'm gonna do things from scratch..anyway thnx for answering ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `ScrollView`'s child height should be set `wrap_content` (for vertical scroll). You're maybe looking for method [`fillViewport()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setFillViewport(boolean)).

Comment: hi i used  android:fillViewport="true" and the problem of the LinearView height thing is solved but i cant scroll right now any where i might have made a mistake ?

Comment: I also  set the LinearView's height to wrap_content and ScrollView's height to fill_parent and i cant scroll..I set the ScrollView's Height to wrap_content and they get super small which is not that suprising i've set the children's height based on their parent with weight ofcourse it wont work with their parent's height to wrap_content :| What should i do ?

Comment: Got it i guess....I need sth like **min_height="fill_parent"** but i cant use fill_parent for min_height any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Do you really have some content you can scroll to? When content isn't bigger than screen, ScrollView isn't scrollable.

Comment: That's exactly my problem...I've said hey contents u guys are each 60% of ur parent with weights and things...but if set the scrollView's height to **wrap_content** and then the LinearView's height to **wrap_content too** it makes a disaster cos **both children and parent are making their height based on the other** so i came up with **min_height="fill_parent"** which is not allowed :| ...